# ASP.NET Core MVC project always causes "InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for <a>. An <a> with a specified 'href' must"

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I coded with that project suddenly during run it gives me that window. after undo all the work i did but no response at all.

[image]

What I understand now that each anchor in the page

[image]

Some how when rendering the framework add to it the `asp-action` and `asp-controller` I don't how.

I'm using VS Code. I don't understand the reason behind that.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: hi,@Mohammed Saied,It's hard to reproduce the issue with what you provided,would you share a  minimal reproducible example that could reproduce the issue?